# Check if the line goes through wall on 2D map

Tags: c++, dictionary, line, collision, intersect

I have 2d map and I want to check if line collides with any element. I need a function that can tell me if the line intersect any object on its way.

Take a look:

[image]

Red lines are not correct (function should return false), and green are (return true).
My collision map is map of boolean with 1 for wall and 0 for empty space.

How to this? I've read that I need to check if the line intersect any wall, but i have completely no idea how to do this on 2d map.

Thanx for any replies.

Comment: do the lines only have endpoints at the centers of cells, or can they be anywhere?

Comment: centers only. Maybe in future I will do sth with it, but now centers only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I imagined that your cells are squares... let say they're unit squares. So, if I have any coordinate, for a point like , which are floats or doubles, they are in cell .

1. you need to know in which cells are the endpoints of the line
2. walk straight from one endpoint to the other and for each cell, test if it's a wall or not
3. return false when a wall is found, true otherwise.

To walk from one endpoint to the other, you need to compute the delta of each axis (call delta_x and delta_y, those values are 'int' because we're talking cells here), i.e. the number of cells it goes on the vertical and on the horizontal. You take the largest of the two. You will use that largest value for your loop. Let say it's this value is D = max(delta_x, delta_y) and XX and YY are the coordinate of the cell of one endpoint.

```
float step = 1.0f / D;
float current_location = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= D; ++i, current_location += step)
{
  int cur_x = XX + current_location * delta_x;
  int cur_y = YY + current_location * delta_y;
  if (intersect_wall(cur_x, cur_y))
    return false;
}
return true;
```

That's it... adapt this to your functions.

Comment: That's a bad idea. I don't mean to say my stuff is the only one worth looking at, but this algorithm has a lot of flaws in many edge cases that you will encounter (very vertical line, or long and slightly going upwards for instance). The general is the same as mine : find the pixels on the line, then check which one are colliding. The algorithm (bresenham, but there are others) I propose is only more accurate and won't have the issues this one will soon show.

Comment: I did that out of my head in 3 minutes... actually, I'm using this approach to draw lines, which gives a simple and a good result. I hope there's better way than this!

Comment: Well, I can only say THIS one worked best. Although its very slow, so Im going to find something faster...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your walls are represented.

If they are rectangle, then look for the [line/segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection) intersection between your line and the 4 segments representing the rectangle.

If they are pixels, you can use the [bresenham line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) algorithm to see if the pixels on the line are on these blocks.

Comment: They are bits on 2d array collision map. Maybe something more? Im newbie :(

Comment: Then go for Bresenham's algorithm. The trick is that you'll have to use the the coordinates being coordinates of the cells, not pixels, and that the goal is not to draw the line. You know the coordinates of the line (beginning and end). Use bresenham's algorithm to find all the blocks on this line. If one of these blocks is a wall, then there is a collision.

Answer (score 1):

If your walls are represented as line-segments you could test for intersection of line-segments as Paul Bourke describes: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/

If your walls are represented as polygons you could clip your test line against the wall polygon and see if the clipping result is non-empty as Paul Bourke describes: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/cliplinetopoly/